# How do you align widgets like CSS float with Flutter UI?

Tags: flutter

Given some `List<Widget>`, how might I achieve the equivalent of CSS float left/right? I have a list of widgets with constant height, but variable width. I would like for them to be laid out like the image:

[image]

Comment: You can simply use one Column with three Rows to create this layout.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget.

```
new Wrap(
    direction: Axis.horizontal,
    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.start,
    spacing: 5,
    runSpacing: 5,
    children: [
    ],
);
```

Comment: Indeed, this what I was also looking for!